# Sending a request to a php web service from iOS

Tags: php, ios, mysql, database, swift

I have a question relating to sending a POST request from an iOS app to a web service written in php, that will ultimately query a MySQL database.

**tldr: How do I view the contents of the POST variables directly in the browser window, without refreshing?**

Long version:

I had written my Swift code in Xcode, with NSURLSession, request, data etc.

I had a php web page set to `var_dump($_POST);` so that I could check that the data was sent in correctly (my data was a hard-coded string in Xcode for testing purposes).

I couldn't for the life of me figure out why I kept getting empty `POST` variables, until I decided to add a test query statement to my web page binding the `POST` variable. Lo and behold, the query ran successfully and my table updated.

I now realise that the reason I thought the `POST` variable was empty was because I was refreshing the web page in order to see the results of my `var_dump`. I now also know that this was deleting the `POST` data, because when I repeated this action with the query statement, my table was getting `NULL` rows.

My question is how do I view the contents of the `POST` variables directly in the browser window, without refreshing? I know this must be a real noob goose chase I've led myself on... but I am a noob.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO here we help people who have problems with their code. If you have a problem with your code(for example an error) post your code into your question and tell us what you expect the code to do, what it actually does and what you have tried to solve this problem. Also take a look at this page here it tells you [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) also take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page there it tells you all you need to know about SO.

Comment: how is this question related to mysql, sowft, ios or database?

Comment: @BRoebie Well the thing is my code actually works... There are no errors anywhere, and it achieves what I want. I just want to know how to access the POST variables from the browser window without refreshing it.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/restclient/

Comment: Are you trying to open a browser AFTER the post and see the value? You need to store and retrieve the value in order to do that.

Comment: @ThomasChia We do not code for you, we help you with a problem in your code. I advise you google what you need to know and when you have a problem feel free to come back here and ask another question.

Comment: @BRoebie Thanks for your guidance, but I am not asking anyone to code anything for me. I hope that's quite clear in my question.

Comment: @Kisaragi Yes that is what i was trying to do. I guess it did not click that I could not just simply display the POST variable by refreshing the page.

Comment: @ThomasChia the only way to check that is sending back the variable as a JSON. Check the answer below. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to modify the service itself to output those values in some way. If this is strictly for debugging, you are better off having the service write out to a log file instead. If this is part of the requesting applications call and the data needs to be displayed to the user, the service should probably return either an XML or JSON string response that your application can parse. Otherwise, you can use Fiddler to monitor your web traffic.

Comment: Yes this was a debugging task. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course overtime you refresh the page you just get an empty variable. 
This is what I used to test if my code was working:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    testPost() // this function will test that the code is sending the variable to your server
    return true
}

func testPost() {

    let variableToPost = "someVariable"

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.yourserver.com/api/v1.0/post.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "variable=\(variableToPost)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
        { data, response, error in

            if error != nil {

                print(error)
                return

            }

            do{

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary


                if let parseJSON = json{


                    let result = parseJSON["status"] as? String
                    let message = parseJSON["message"] as? String


                    if result == "Success"{

                        //this should return your variable

                        print(message)


                    }else{

                        // print the message if it failed ie. Missing required field
                        print(message)

                    }

                }//if parse

            }  catch let error as NSError {
                print("error in registering: \(error)")


            } //catch

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

then your php file will only check if there is no empty post and return the variable  as JSON:
**post.php**

```
<?php
$postValue = htmlentities($_POST["variable"]);

 if(empty($postValue))
 {
 $returnValue["status"] = "error";
 $returnValue["message"] = "Missing required field";
 echo json_encode($returnValue);
 return;
 } else {

 $returnValue["status"] = "success";
 $returnValue["message"] = "your post value is ".$postValue."";
 echo json_encode($returnValue);
 }
```